# Magento 2.3 - Product Attribute Options Sort

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, attributes

I want to sort the product attribute option, can anyone help me which file I need to change for it.

[image]

Ex. The brand attribute has so many options, I want to sort it alphabetical order in the admin side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have brand attribute has so many option i want to sort alphabetical order

Comment: admin side ????

Comment: yes in admin site